# skip specific line that contains certain value when you read pandas data frame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

When you read the csv using command pd.read_csv,
How do I skip the line that contains specific value in a row? 
If in 50th, 55th row, the 1st column has the value, 100, so I want to skip those lines when I read the csv file. 
How I can put those command in a read-in command like pd.read_csv('read.csv')?
total length of the value is 300.

Comment: what is length of value?

Comment: What is the difference between dropping them later, and not reading them at all? You might simply do: `pd.read_csv('file.csv').query('col1 != 100')`...

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^THAT!  @Kartik, why isn't that an answer?

Comment: Because, @piRSquared, I am not sure what the OP really wants. Also, I don't know what the name of the column is. But, you're right, I should post it as answer, and let OP comment on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the difference between dropping them later, and not reading them at all? You might simply do:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv').query('col1 != 100')
```

Comment: Actually there is no difference! Thank you! it worked!

Comment: More generally, the difference is that that value might not match the desired dtype of your column.

Comment: You can always `.infer_objects()` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) later.

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to pre-parse the file. Use a generator to read the file, and then only `yield` the lines that you want. You can then use that to read the lines you want into a `StringIO` object, and pass that object in inplace of the filepath to `read_csv`.

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            parts = line.split(',')
            if parts[0] != '100':
                yield line

stream = StringIO.StringIO()
stream.writelines(read_file('foo.txt'))
stream.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(stream)
```