# read_csv read rows with value contained in a column of another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with large dataframes (15gb) and every time I try to open them it raises a memory error.

I successfully opened dataframe A, which the first column is an ID contained also in dataframe B. 
Now, B has many more rows and ID that I don't care and, since I can't filter rows after opening it due to the memory error, I was trying to filter the rows that I need while opening it.

By following this post [skip specific line that contains certain value when you read pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647473/skip-specific-line-that-contains-certain-value-when-you-read-pandas-data-frame) I tried to use:

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

emptylist = []
def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            parts = line.split(',')
            if parts[0] not in emptylist:
                emptylist.append(parts[0])
                if parts[0] in set(idlist):
                    yield line

stream = StringIO.StringIO()
stream.writelines(read_file('B.csv'))
stream.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(stream)
```

where emptylist should contain the unique values of dataframe B's ID, and idlist is the column ID of Dataframe A converted to list.

The problem is that it's still giving me memory error at stream.writelines(read_file('B.csv')), and I don't understand why, since the number of rows should be exactly the same of Dataframe A, and the number of columns of B is only 2, against the 3 of dataset A, that instead I can open.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's still the remories error because you still read the whole `B.csv` to RAM to process. You can use this:

```
with open("B.csv") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        do_something_with(line)
```

It only reads one line at a time. When the next line is read, the previous one will be garbage collected unless you have stored a reference to it somewhere else.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but I don't understand, should I use only the lines you provided (with the if clause instead of do something...) or I need to substitute them in my code inside the function? So keeping the stream and other stuff

Comment: Instead of loading the whole file to a variable and filter or do something with it (which may get an error by full of RAM), now you can iterate line by line to take only important lines and maybe save it to another file (much smaller than the original one).

Comment: Uhm, I've tried but it seems that it doesn't work, since every line is some kind of separate elements, so if I create an empty dict() and then dictionary[line[0]] = line[1] doesn't work

Comment: Yes, of course each row is a separate element, and it will be separate by comma, that's why it's called `csv` file format. You just need to separate each row and get your value. If not, I really dont know what do you want